# Variance Homogeneity for a model created with lmerTest

Tags: r, regression, lme4, mixed-models, lmertest

I have run the model:

```
model2 <- lmer(tas ~ station
              + (1|date), data = all5)
```

where station is a categorical variable with 4 levels.
I want to check for variance homogeneity.
I find the residuals from `lmerresid <- resid(model2)`.
If I run the levene test:
`leveneTest(lmerresid ~ all5$station)` I get p = 0.6572 so it implies homogeneity of variances.
If I make the boxplots it implies homogeneity of variances:

```
boxplot(lmerresid ~ all5$station)
```

[image]
But if I plot residuals vs fited then there is sth wrong:
#Plot vs factors

```
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
plot(lmerresid ~ fitted(model2))
```

[image]

Are the variances homogeneous?

Comment: Since this question is about interpreting statistical results, it's better suited to stats.stackexchange.com  Stack Overflow is for questions of specific code problems. Please consider deleting this question and asking on stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: The last graph indicates that the model is poorly specified (how many dates you got? What if you remove ``date``?)

Comment: I have 210 days.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you use levene tests on mixed models (as opposed to `lm()`), though I could be wrong there.

THAT SAID

I have found the easiest way to test models for validity is to use `library(performance)`.

`performance(model2)`

"Super easy, barely and inconvenience". I'm not going to say it's perfect* for what you have in mind, but it will run most (if not all) of the tests that you may need to check your model. This along with the standard `lmer()` output, should enable you to interpret your model.

`*` You will need to delve into the manual to understand all the appropriate uses of the tests.